# StarTeam share change request across multiple branches or views

Tags: version-control, configuration, configuration-management, starteam

We currently have a simple Star Team setup with a couple of branches or views as they seem to be refered to in Star Team:

```
--Production
  --Staging
    --Development
    --Trunk
```

We would like to "Share" or create a "Referenced View" of a Change Request (CR) that would be visbile on all of these views, but we would like it to be updated across all the branches when a change is made to it.

I have tried Ctrl + dragging and dropping the CR to the various views but they dont get updated when I make changes to it. Its as if they are being treated as individual copies of the CR. I also tried checking and unchecking the "Branch on Change" checkbox for the behavior of each of the items but that seems to have no effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "Floating" Radio Button under "Advanced | Behavior" on the "Configuraion" Tab?

Georg

Comment: That was the issue. You have to uncheck branch on change, and then you have to make sure it is set to flaoting configuration. I had it set to a fixed configuration which is why it wouldnt update.